# Session Cookies not being deleted after sessions ends

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm creating a session cookie via JavaScipt. The cookie is being created successfully, and when I check in Chrome developer tools, I see the cookie with an "Expires-Max Age" value of 'Session'. When I close the application in the Chrome tab, or when I close the entire browser, and re-enter the application, the cookie is still there. How long does it take for the cookie to actually be removed? Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried to don't set an expiry date? Cause if i remember well, defaults expire at the end of the session

Comment: Are you closing all tabs?

Comment: I did't specifically close all the tabs. But I closed the tab containing the app, and then closed the entire browser. But I didn't explicitly close all tabs.

Comment: @keypaul - As far as Chrome is concerned, this is a session cookie, because it shows it as such in Developer tools.